# template-argument-reduction for return type

Tags: c++, templates, std

I have this function:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator> > 
split(    const std::vector<int>& vector,size_t slices){

...

}
```

and since it`s quite verbose, and I probably will need to split other kinds of vectors in the future, I want to make it template-based, but this tryout failed:

```
 template<typename T> 
  std::vector<std::pair< std::vector<T>::iterator, std::vector<T>::iterator> >
  split( const std::vector<T>& vector, size_t slices) 

    ...

 }
```

There are two problems in what I can see:
1 - I cant use vector or map or list, only vector.
2 - I don`t understand the template-reduction stuff in a good way yet.

any explanation appreciated.

Comment: And why did this tryout fail? You should always post the error message. (I think you might be missing two `typename`s).

Comment: You should probably either take a non-const vector reference or use `const_iterator` in your result type.

Comment: Zeta, the problem was the typename, but not just the typename, since I was passing vector<T> instead of just T ( as vector<type> beign T. ). Fozi, thanks, updated in my code. :)

Answer (score 1):

> 1 - I cant use vector or map or list, [...]

If you want to handle generically *all containers*, then you should not use the `std::vector` template in the first place (and you should not name your function argument `vector` either):

```
template<typename C>
std::vector<std::pair<typename C::iterator, typename C::iterator>>
split(C const& cont, size_t slices)
{
    ...
}
```

Also notice the use of the `typename` keyword, which is necessary when specifying a qualified, dependent type name.

Comment: I used std::container so I at least could use one container, since I didn't know how to make it use all ( I tougth I could use the vector-type as Template argument, but not the vector<type> as a type. ), thanks, your answer is what I was looking for. :D

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T> 
  std::vector<std::pair< typename T::iterator, typename T::iterator> >
  split( const T& vector, size_t slices) 

    ...

 }
```

You are missing `typename`, and you can replace the container's type.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `typename`:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<
    std::pair<
        typename std::vector<T>::iterator,
        typename std::vector<T>::iterator
    >
>
split( const std::vector<T>& vector, size_t slices)
{ /* ... */ }
```

See [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords/613132#613132) for more information about `typename`.